# Как правильно отфильтровать людей по месту проживания в БД Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, group-by

У меня єсть БД с больше чем 800 документами, вида:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5adf3c1544abaca147cdd34b"},"index":2,"guid":"bd579f65-83a2-4966-8e33-da078369eb15",
"isActive":false,    
"balance":"$3,118.30",    
"picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32",
"age":40,"
eyeColor":"blue",

"name":"Macias Shannon",

"gender":"male",

"company":"NORSUL",

"email":"maciasshannon@norsul.com",

"phone":"+1 (846) 566-2908",

"address":"221 Gardner Avenue, Tetherow, Virginia, 464",

"about":"Cupidatat ad esse ad nulla aute eiusmod veniam minim esse labore id et ipsum. Pariatur esse qui consequat ad eiusmod adipisicing enim est excepteur esse qui eiusmod. Minim eu enim cupidatat in id nulla culpa esse ut velit elit incididunt quis. Ex laborum deserunt incididunt in. Deserunt occaecat occaecat ex culpa dolore occaecat amet magna non adipisicing. Magna qui voluptate aliquip ea ut commodo cupidatat adipisicing et irure ad velit. Magna cillum Lorem aute dolor eu nostrud sit ullamco incididunt nisi enim culpa eiusmod pariatur.\r\n",

"registered":"2016-04-14T03:22:40 -03:00",

"latitude":74.541168,

"longitude":139.707963,

"tags":["dolor","cillum","sint","do","do","proident","fugiat"],

"friends":[{"id":0,"name":"Dennis Sawyer"},{"id":1,"name":"Durham Pollard"},{"id":2,"name":"Tammy Griffin"}],

"greeting":"Hello, Macias Shannon! You have 1 unread messages.",

"favoriteFruit":"apple"}
```

Нужно найти всех людей которые проживают в штате Вирджиния,  при группировке по

`_id: "$address"`

Профильтрирует только по адресу, а как найти людей прожывающих определённом штате?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
var reg = /virginia/ig;
db.collection.find({adress:{$reg:reg})
```

Comment: не работает почему-то